# angularjs - not able to invalidate input (Object doesn't support property or method '$setValidity')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-validation

I try to do the following

```
if ($scope.RetypePassword != $scope.resource.Password) {
     $scope.resource.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", false);
} else {
     $scope.resource.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", true);
}
```

but fail with this error

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method '$setValidity'
```

What can the reason be?

resource.Password is databound to an input like this

```
<input type="password" ng-model="resource.Password" name="Password" />
```

Comment: Is `$scope.resource` the form model?

Comment: @dcodesmith sorry I missed that in the question, but it is only an object bound to some input-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have form name `resource` because you has model which already has object in `resource`, try some different from name will solve your problem
like name="myForm"

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="password" ng-model="resource.Password" name="Password" />
</form>
```

**Code**

```
if ($scope.RetypePassword != $scope.resource.Password) {
     $scope.myForm.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", false);
} else {
     $scope.myForm.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", true);
}
```

Comment: @Robert I added an answer..two minutes before than him..do check it hovering mouse on `answered 1 hour ago` text..you will come to know who added answer first

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `resource.RetypePassword` is a scope object (model), this is not the same as [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) you need. This controller is not exposed to scope directly. However you can access it via parent `form` object by input name.

So in case your HTML looks like this:

```
<form novalidate name="form">
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div><input type="password" ng-model="resource.Password" name="Password" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <div><input type="password" ng-model="resource.RetypePassword" name="RetypePassword" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then you would be able to do this

```
if ($scope.resource.RetypePassword != $scope.resource.Password) {
    $scope.form.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", false);
} else {
    $scope.form.Password.$setValidity("missmatch", true);
}
```

Check a little demonstration of the principle.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tVFlytaW2WVJfLdiq4o2?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I totally missed this in the examples that the forms name where used.